# file download popup is not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, httphandler

I am working on ASP.NET Web form application.
My requirement is to show excel file download popupbox when user clicks on the given link (This link is on poppage not on aspx page.).
I have a aspx page with link. When user clicks,it will call js function through that we call web service method to generate html for popup screen.

**CODE**:

```
 function showListModelFromGenrator(divId) {
    var lowner = $("#" + hdnLoggedInOwnerID)[0].value;
    var sowner = $("#" + hdnSelectedOwnnerID)[0].value;
    var commID = $("#" + hdnCommunityId)[0].value;


    var controlid = '#' + divId;
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + '/' + "WebServices/ExtraInfoWebService.asmx/GetProductActivityStatus",

        data: { LoggedInOwnerId: lowner, SelectedOwnerId: sowner, CommunityId: commID },
        success: function (response) {
            $(controlid).dialog("destroy");
            $(controlid).dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 560,
                height: 370,
                resizable: false

            }).empty().append(response.text);
            $(controlid).dialog('open');
            var busyBox = new BusyBoxWrapper()
            busyBox.HideBusyBoxAfter(5);
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

**web method**:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string GetProductActivityStatus(int LoggedInOwnerId, int SelectedOwnerId, int CommunityId)
    {
        StringBuilder stringAuditStatus = new StringBuilder();
        Audit objdata = new Audit();
        try
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            int ownerID = LoggedInOwnerId;
            if (SelectedOwnerId != 0)
                ownerID = SelectedOwnerId;

            dt = objdata.GetListmodeldata(ownerID, CommunityId);

            stringAuditStatus.Append(@"<table><tr class=addressTableHeader><td>Code</td>" +
                                            "<td>Description</td>" +
                                            "<td>Status</td>" +
                                            "<td>Date</td></tr>");
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                stringAuditStatus.Append(


                                            "<tr><td>" + item["Code"] + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + item["Description"] + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + item["Status"] + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + item["Date"] + "</td></tr>");
            }
            stringAuditStatus.Append("</table>");
            stringAuditStatus.Append("<a id=lnkViewProductCodeStatus runat='Server' href='#' onclick='javascript:ExportExel();'>DownloadListModel</a>");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return stringAuditStatus.ToString();
    }
```

when user clicks on "lnkViewProductCodeStatus " (above created by web method).
we call JS function `ExportExcel` which calls the handler method to process file to download.

```
function ExportExel(){
    var abc;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: baseUrl + '/' + "WebServices/ExtraInfoWebService.asmx/Urlhttphandler",
        data: {},
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            //window.open(msg.d);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: msg.d,
                data: {},
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    //window.open(msg.d);
                }
            });
        }
    });
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {


        string FullFilePath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Certificates/" + "ExcelFile.xls");
        System.IO.FileInfo file = new System.IO.FileInfo(FullFilePath);

        if (file.Exists)
        {
            //For more MIME types list http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147%28VS.85%29.aspx
            context.Response.ContentType = MIMETypeUtility.MIMETypeDescription(MIMEType.Excel);
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + file.Name + "\"");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
            context.Response.Flush();
            context.Response.End();
        }



    }
```

when I debug application call goes correctly to hanlder but file download popup is not coming.same code i tried on page ( not on popup) it works fine.can anyone guide me why this is not working in my case.

Thanks a lot,
Prashant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to save a file using ajax. It will get the data but the download dialog will never be shown. See [Download a file by jQuery.Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/how-to-download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax) for more information.

I recently had a similar requirement myself and ended up having the javascript Excel download function create a form on the page dynamically (with the action pointing to the .ashx handler that generates the Excel file). The function then populated the form with hidden inputs containing any parameters required by the .ashx handler and then finally submitting it.

An example based on what I did:

```
 function ExportExcel() {
    var formFragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    $(form).attr("action", baseUrl + "/WebServices/ExtraInfoWebService.asmx/Urlhttphandler")
        .attr("method", "POST");

    var inputField = document.createElement("input");
    $(inputField).attr("type", "hidden")
        .attr("id", "someId")
        .attr("name", "someId")
        .val(3);
    form.appendChild(inputField);

    formFragment.appendChild(form);
    $("body").append(formFragment);
    $(form).submit();
};
```